# Switft get html value of amazon product image

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, html-parsing, swiftsoup

I am trying to get the image of a amazon product inside my app. I inspected the image in my browser and found out that their `class-Name` is `gc-design-img-preview`. There are actually more `Elements` with the same class so I tried only getting the first one.

This is what I tried:

```
func getAmazonImage(doc: Document) -> String {
    let images: Elements? = try? doc.getElementsByClass("gc-design-img-preview")
    
    guard (images?.first()) != nil else { return "nope" }
        
    guard  let imageUrl : String = try! images?.first()!.text() else { return "nope2" }
    
    print("image: " + imageUrl)
    
    return imageUrl
}
```

However this is not returning anything and instead just returning an empty `String`... What am I missing here? I am using `SwiftSoup`, maybe there is another way to do this?

**Update:**

I think this is what I need but in `Swift`:

```
const imgSrc = document.querySelector('li.image.item.itemNo0.maintain-height.selected img').getAttribute('src')

console.log(imgSrc) // https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71y%2BUGuJl5L._SX522_.jpg
```

Comment: I went to an Amazon product page but did not found any product with this class-Name. Could you provide an example page to investigate further?

Comment: @ManuelMB I tried finding it but I couldnt... No idea what I did. Anyway, the main issue remains the same. I would like to get the main image from any amazon product.

Answer (score 2):

To do it with SwiftSoup:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftSoup

class ViewController: UIViewController {

func getProductImage(url: URL)-> String{
    var result = ""
    do {
        let html = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
        let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parseBodyFragment(html)
        let img: Element = try doc.select("li.image.item.itemNo0.maintain-height.selected img").first()!
        
        let imgOuterHtml: String = try img.outerHtml();
       
        let chunks = imgOuterHtml.components(separatedBy: "\"")

        result = chunks[5]
    }
    catch {
       print(error)
    }
    
    return result
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08FC6C75Y") else {
        fatalError("Can not get url")
    }
     let imgUrl = getProductImage(url: url)
     print(imgUrl)  // https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61o7ai%2BYDoL._SL1441_.jpg
  }
 }
```

Comment: it is not working for every product though.. no idea why

Comment: Could you provide an url where it is not working?

Comment: this is not working for me: https://www.amazon.com/Bedtime-Originals-Plush-Monkey-Ollie/dp/B0084DS9EE/ref=gwm_nc_?pf_rd_s=grid-5&pf_rd_t=Gateway-AmazonGlobal&pf_rd_i=mobile&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=6W6VPWZ7XJTAGP4ZJQA9&pf_rd_p=1bbe5685-7635-4342-ab21-7dc6f3e392ba&pd_rd_i=B0084DS9EE

Comment: Apparently Amazon is not consistent returning the results for all products, so another methodology would have to be used. 

At this moment I am experiencing issues with XCode and can not debug because I got the following error: 

Cannot create Swift scratch context (couldn't load the Swift stdlib) site:developer.apple.com 

I will try to solve it and post a different solution

Comment: ah good old xcode issues...I think it is actually retrieving the right element, but with my example the `chunks` are different I think but I am not sure. Let me know if your Xcode is working again and if you can reproduce the issue

Comment: Yes, in the working example chunks[5] get the content inside data-old-hires="", but in the url that it is not working is because data-old-hires="" has not content inside it.

Comment: But the url is still there. Maybe there is a better way to extract it than by splitting it at „/„ ? Do you know any more generic way ?

Comment: Hey Manuel! I just checked my app and all of a sudden it is no longer working for me... Same code! Is the function above still working for you????

Comment: Hey Chris, you are right, it is not working now, Amazon could have changed the output code, I am trying a different approach and will post it as a new comment at the end of this post if it works.

Comment: any success so far ?

Comment: Not yet, I am trying with an WKWebView and wait until the page is full load, but at the moment still not success.

Comment: It is weird, if you inspect the image it still has the same `selector` for me. So why is it not working??

Comment: Try using this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65604771/4191561

And put a breakpoint at this line:

let img: Element = try doc.select("li.image.item.itemNo0.maintain-height.selected img").first()!

When stop in the breakpoint, write in the terminal:

po doc

And look at the resulting HTML output, it doesn't have the selector

Comment: mmm weird :/ any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hi Chris, I will try it again when I found some available time to do it, but at the moment I am quite busy with other tasks, sorry.

Comment: fair enough, no problem! Let me know if you find anything :)

Comment: Hi Chris, I found a way to do it, take a look:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65832880/4191561

Comment: Hi Chris you are unaccepting answers that previously works ok because they stop working, and I think this is not fair. If Amazon change the code in the HTML of its pages it is normal that solutions that initially works ok stop working, If you need someone to adapt the code every time Amazon do some changes hire a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, in this url:
[https://www.amazon.com/DualSense-Wireless-Controller-PlayStation-5/dp/B08FC6C75Y/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&fst=as%3Aoff&pf_rd_i=16225016011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=03b28c2c-71e9-4947-aa06-f8b5dc8bf880&pf_rd_r=CSWVBS40MDKKJYXEJ0AH&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-3&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1489016289&rnid=16225016011&s=videogames-intl-ship&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08FC6C75Y)

```
const imgSrc = document.querySelector('li.image.item.itemNo0.maintain-height.selected img').getAttribute('src')

console.log(imgSrc) // https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71y%2BUGuJl5L._SX522_.jpg
```

Comment: how would I do that with SwiftSoup?

Answer (score 0):

After update XCode I can debug again :

This code works ok in both urls:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftSoup

class ViewController: UIViewController {

func getProductImage(url: URL)-> String{
    var result = ""
    do {
        let html = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
        let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parseBodyFragment(html)
        let img: Element = try doc.select("li.image.item.itemNo0.maintain-height.selected img").first()!
        let imgOuterHtml: String = try img.outerHtml();
        let imgUrl = getImageUrl(imgOuterHtml)
        result = imgUrl
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return result
}

func getImageUrl(_ input: String)->String{
    let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
    let matches = detector.matches(in: input, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count))
    
    guard let range = Range(matches[0].range, in: input) else { fatalError("Can not get range") }
    let url = input[range]
    
    return String(url).components(separatedBy: "&")[0]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08FC6C75Y") else {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0084DS9EE") else {
        fatalError("Can not get url")
    }
    let imgUrl = getProductImage(url: url)
    //print(imgUrl)// https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61o7ai%2BYDoL._SL1441_.jpg
    print(imgUrl)  // https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ZmuuKMtmL._SY450_.jpg
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the second url the image can be obtained in different resolutions, you van get it from different attributes data-midres-replacement, data-zoom-hires or data-a-hires, in the code are all the options, but some of them are commented.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftSoup

class ViewController: UIViewController {

func getProductImage(url: URL)-> String{
    var result = ""
    do {
        let html = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
        let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parseBodyFragment(html)
                                            
        let img: Element = try doc.select(".image-size-wrapper.fp-image-wrapper.image-block-display-flex img").first()!  
        let src  = try img.attr("src")  

        if src.contains("data:image/gif;base64"){
            
            let dataMidresReplacement  = try img.attr("data-midres-replacement")
            print("dataMidresReplacement: \(dataMidresReplacement)") // dataMidresReplacement: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ZmuuKMtmL._AC_SY350_.jpg
            result = dataMidresReplacement
            /*
            let dataZoomHires  = try img.attr("data-zoom-hires")
            print("dataZoomHires: \(dataZoomHires)") // dataZoomHires: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ZmuuKMtmL._AC_SL1500_.jpg
            result = dataZoomHires
            */
            /*
            let dataHires  = try img.attr("data-a-hires")
            print("dataHires: \(dataHires)") // dataHires: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ZmuuKMtmL._AC_SY1000_.jpg
            result = dataHires
            */
        } else {
            result = src
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    
    return result
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
   //guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08FC6C75Y") else {
   guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0084DS9EE") else {
        fatalError("Can not get url")
    }
    let imgUrl = getProductImage(url: url)
    //print(imgUrl) // https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61o7ai%2BYDoL._AC_SY350_QL15_.jpg
    print(imgUrl)  // data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
   }
}
```